# How to move words which dont fit automatically to next line in a libgdx label?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a really long sentence. Should I use some other widget than Label?
When I set the Label's text to a really large sentence, the words which are after the maxwidth of the label, get chopped of.

A possible hack is manually adding "\n" at places where you want to move to next line in the String. But this is not possible for automating this process.

The label in this picture is a long one, and its text is as follows -

"I am in a garden. \n I am in a garden. I am in a garden."

How can I move the last word automatically to the third line in the same label?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String insertNewlineChars(String textToDisplay, Float maxLabelWidth, BitmapFont font)
{

    float textWidth=0;
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(textToDisplay.split(" ")));
    String addWordsToSentence;

    //add first word
    String nextWord = words.get(0) ;
    addWordsToSentence = nextWord + " ";
    textWidth = font.getBounds(addWordsToSentence).width;

    //add 2nd to last word
    for(int i=1;i<words.size();i++)
    {
        nextWord = words.get(i);
        textWidth += font.getBounds(nextWord).width;

        //add word to a new line
        if(textWidth >  maxLabelWidth)
        {
            //push to next line
            textWidth = font.getBounds(nextWord).width;
            addWordsToSentence = addWordsToSentence.concat("\n" + nextWord + " ");
        }

        //add word to the same line
        else
        {
            addWordsToSentence = addWordsToSentence.concat(nextWord + " ");
        }

    }
    return addWordsToSentence;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the width of your textview (just `textview.getWidth()`), calculate the width of the actual text by this method:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.measureText("your text here");
```

And compare the together, if the actual text width greater than the textview width, add `\n`.

**UPDATE:**
In your case, instead of calculating the whole actual text, just calculate character by character, sum up the width and compare to the textview width.

Job done. Hope this helps.